# Django issues with google oauth2

Tags: python, django, google-oauth

I'm seeing issues with my social authentication login with Google and am hoping for some help. Any idea what is going on? Facebook and Twitter logins work well but google has me stumped. Thanks in advance!

The error message that I am seeing is "Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Non-public domains not allowed: http://www.localhost:8000/complete/google-oauth2/" However the URI in the credentials section is set to
`http://localhost:8000/complete/google-oauth2/`

I'm calling this on the login screen with has this as the link to login with google.

```
<a class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-google" href="{% url 'social:begin' 'google-oauth2' %}">
<i class="fa fa-google"></i>Sign up with Google</a>
```

The urls in the project are set to this.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^store/', include('store.urls'), name='store'),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
    url('', include('social.apps.django_app.urls', namespace='social')),
    # url('^soc/', include('social.apps.django_app.urls', namespace='social')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

and I think I have the backends set properly as they are:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
    'social.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
    'social.backends.google.GoogleOAuth',
    'social.backends.twitter.TwitterOAuth',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

#Social Auth Keys/Secrets
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY = 'set to the key given'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = 'set to the secret given'
```

Comment: You can not try this on localhost. It has to be on a public domain. A workaround to test the code is to host your code in an AWS instance.